# Why text in p tag can't be setted vertical-align:middle?

Tags: html, css

```css
div{
    width:300px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:70px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    hello world
</div>
```

The text `hello world` is in center status both vertically and horizontally.
Now just add a p tag for `hello world`, nothing else changed for css above.

```css
div{
    width:300px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:70px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the height from div or set overflow:hidden on div

Comment: Because a `p` tag has a default top margin, furthermore, as the `line-height` is the same as the `height`, the `vertical-align:middle;` has no effect in your case. If you were to remove `line-height` a `p` will still not center vertically, as `vertical-align:middle;` works on text and inline elements, which the `p` isn't, being a `block` element.

Comment: Also note, the `div` CSS rule is trying to align the `p` tag, not the `p` tag's text. If to vertical align the text in the `p` tag, you need to add it to your CSS too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your browser's code inspector, you can notice that the `p` tag got a `margin-top` and a `margin-bottom`.

Why is that?
In most browers, the `p` tag has a default value of `1em` on both top and bottom margins, which results to that kind of result:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

/* I added a background to make it visual */
p {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

So, the only thing you need to do is to set the `margin` to `0` to render it like you want:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

/* This is the only thing I added */
p { 
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `vertical-align` work by using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`:

```css
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: table;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use `display: flex`:

```css
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

p{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

You can use also use `position: absolute`, but beware when using this, because it might mess up your layout:

```css
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

p{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```